# How to release a character set?

Tags: objective-c

I have a question about text field. I am writing to let the user only can enter number into the text field.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    static NSCharacterSet *charSet = nil;
    if(!charSet) {
        charSet = [[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet] retain];
    }
    NSRange location = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];
    return (location.location == NSNotFound);
}
```

Above is the code, it works fine now, the only thing is how can I release charSet since I retain it already. If I release it here, it will crash. Please text me the way. Or is it still ok if I keep it retain like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never have retained `charSet` in the first place. It is autoreleased when it comes to you: it lives long enough for the rest of your code to run, and then goes out of existence all by itself.

Of course if you use iOS 5 and ARC you'll never have to worry about retain and release again...

EDIT: Oh, I see what the problem is, you're assigning to a static. Okay then, just retain it as you are doing, and let it leak later on. Either that or use an instance variable and that way you can memory-manage it. Sorry about getting the answer wrong the first time, but better to admit that I read carelessly... :)

ANOTHER EDIT: But *why* are you assigning to a static? Do you really think this is saving you a lot of time? Isn't this a case of "premature optimization"? Computers are really fast, much much faster than the user can type; I think your device can very happily calculate `[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet]` every time through this routine without slowing things down.

Comment: See the following about `NSCharacterSet`s and performance considerations: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CharacterSets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000146-SW5. In other words, may not be such a bad idea to cache it...

Comment: @NSGod - That documentation is about mutable character sets - there are no mutable character sets in his code. However, as I said, if he wants to cache it he can either leak it as a static or cache it as something that he can actually memory manage, like an instance variable...

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to validate that the user has entered digits, then you can either do

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"]] length]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

or just make the keyboard the numberpad.

Your method only checks that the input has a number, not that it consists only of numbers. Unless you've disabled the copy/paste feature, you need to check all of the input is valid.